# FuelPHPでモジュールから自作クラスを継承する

Tags: php, fuelphp

現在Fuelphpでモジュールを使用したアプリケーションを作成しています。
そこで「コアクラスを継承した自作クラス」を継承したコントローラーを
作成しようとしているのですが、このコントローラーで「コアクラスを継承した
自作クラス」を読み込む際にエラーが発生します。

「コアクラスを継承した自作クラス」はfuelphp\fuel\app\classes\myselfフォルダ内にあり、

```
<?php
namespace Fuel\Core;

    class Myself_ControllerPublic extends Controller_Template
    {
             // 実際の処理
    }
```

となります。
また作成するコントローラーはfuelphp\fuel\app\modules\sample\classes\controller
フォルダ内にあり、

```
<?php
namespace sample;

class Controller_Foo extends \Myself_ControllerPublic 
{
    // 実際の処理
}
```

となります。
ここで名前空間、extendsの指定を色々変えてみたのですが、どうやっても'Not Found'か
'does not contain class'となってしまいます。
fuelphp\fuel\app\classesクラスの自作クラスは命名規則さえ正しければ自動で読み込むと
思っていたのですが、上手く読み込むことが出来ません。

またMyself_ControllerPublicクラスをモジュール内に置こうとすると、今度はこのクラスを
Controller_Fooで読み込むことが出来ません。

このようなモジュールにおいて「コアクラスを継承した自作クラス」を継承したコントローラーを
動作させるのはどうすればよいでしょうか？
（「コアクラスを継承した自作クラス」はモジュール内外、どちらにあっても構いません。）

ご存知のかたがいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授のほど、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: まず、自作クラスに名前空間`Fuel\Core`を使うのは間違っています。「fuelphp\fuel\app\classesクラスの自作クラスは命名規則さえ正しければ自動で読み込む」というのは正しいですが、命名規則についてきちんと理解されていないようです。そこをきちんと把握された方がよろしいかと思います。

Comment: すいません。名前空間「Fuel\Core」を消し忘れていました。(Coreクラスにこの定義があったので、念のため試してみたのですが、消し忘れていました。)  あと質問したばかりで申し訳ないのですが、本日解決いたしました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コアクラスを継承した自作クラスの名前ですが、
class Myself_ControllerPublic extends Controller_Template
ではなく、
class Myself_Controller_Public extends Controller_Template
ではないでしょうか？

モジュール側の継承するクラス名も
class Controller_Foo extends \Myself_Controller_Public
でどうでしょうか？

アンダーバーでディレクトリの区切りとなっています。
http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/general/coding_standards.html

Comment: モジュールを使う際の前提として、
/fuel/app/config/config.php で

//'module_paths' => array(
// APPPATH.'modules'.DS
//),
という部分のコメントアウトを外す必要がありますが、こちらは大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: すいません。この問題なのですが、本日無事解決出来ました。ありがとうございました。ちなみに「Myself_ControllerPublic」クラスですが、「myself」フォルダ内には「controller」フォルダがないので、「_」は不要なのではと思っていますが、違いましたでしょうか？なおmodule_pathsはちゃんとコメントアウトは外してあります。

Comment: ファイルが`app/classes/myself/controllerpublic.php`なら、Fuel的にはクラス名は`Myself_Controllerpublic`となり、PHPはクラス名の大文字小文字を区別しないので`Myself_ControllerPublic`でもたぶん問題はないでしょう。なので、この回答は回答になってないものと思われます。

Comment: コメントが遅くなりました。解決して良かったですね。
私の回答ですが、ご指摘の通りcontrollerフォルダに配置されたものだと勘違いしていました。classes配下であれば記載されたパスで大丈夫ですね。